# per-user Maven properties

Tags: java, maven-2

In my Maven build I would like to be able to define default values (e.g. for database connection) in pom.xml, but I would like the user to be able to override these without having to modify `pom.xml` directly.

By way of example, in an Ant build you can define default properties in `foo.properties`, but Ant will look for overrides for each of these in a `foo.$USERNAME.properties`. The latter is generally not checked into source control, which eliminates the problem of developers accidentally committing their overrides of the default properties. Does Maven offer a similar facility?

To make the problem a bit more concrete, assume I have the following defined in `pom.xml`

```
<properties>
  <db.url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.10.10.10:1433/somedb</db.url>
  <db.driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</db.driver>
  <db.username>default_user</db.username>
  <db.password>secret</db.password>
</properties>
```

Can a user override these properties without editing the pom.xml directly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify properties on the command line using `-Dpropertyname=value`, or the user can specify properties in their `.m2/settings.xml`.

Comment: +1 the settings.xml file is a local file for the user - best place for things like this

Comment: It looks like I can achieve this by defining an `<activeByDefault>` profile in `settings.xml` that contains the overriding property values, is that right?

Comment: You can but be aware that activeByDefault profiles aren't selected if you specify _any_ profile at all when building. I'd just put them in the normal properties section of the POM if I were you, and let the user override them.

Comment: could you show an example of how a user can override the properties above in `settings.xml` without using a `<activeByDefault>` profile?

Comment: Oh sorry I misread your comment - I thought you mean an activeByDefault profile in the POM. Yeah, you need to put it in a profile in the `settings.xml`.

Comment: @artbristol - thanks for the reply. If I put the overrides in a profile in `settings.xml` and the profile is `activeByDefault`, will the overrides still be used if the user specifies additional profiles on the command line?

Comment: No, but you can put an `<activeProfiles>` section in `settings.xml` which is always active (I think)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with build profiles. See [Introduction to build profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) for more information.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how I can use build profiles to solve the problem DB connections problem described above?

Answer (score 1):

I used `settings.xml` to override these properties by adding the following to the `<profiles>` section

```
<profile>
  <id>override-database-properties</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>refreshDB</name>
    </property>
  </activation>

  <properties>
    <db.schema_name>store_don</db.schema_name>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

In this case the overrides will only take effect if a `-DrefreshDB` is passed to the `mvn` command. To activate these overrides every time Maven is invoked also add the following to `settings.xml`

```
<activeProfiles> 
  <activeProfile>alwaysActiveProfile</activeProfile> 
</activeProfiles>
```

If the profile is added to `<activeProfiles>` then the `<activation>` element should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add properties on the command line, but set some settings once (and if you can accept the default being empty strings); you could use environment variables like this:

```
<something>${env.ENVNAME}</something>
<!-- something will be blank "" unless ENVNAME is set -->
```

*Edit:* I've been trying to find a way of defining a default values for `${variable}` if the variable is empty/undefined, but I've not found anything, this seems to be missing (the frequent suggestion is to use profiles but it's not quite the same). 
I'd prefer if you could just set some environment variables and have sensible defaults so that you could just run `mvn clean install` (and not the 20-40 character strings I normally use to build our project). *If default values is possible I'd love hear how...*

BTW, if you're already used to Ant, I've heard that you can call Ant tasks from maven somehow (don't know how, though), maybe you could use that somehow?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but a default value of empty strings won't work